# Opening specific email in Outlook express or Apple desktop mail inbox

Tags: javascript, outlook

I need JavaScript code that would on user click open Outlook Express or Apple desktop mail inbox and show that specific email on which it was clicked in web browser.
The email link in web browser was previously dragged from inbox view of Outlook Express or Apple desktop mail application.
Is it actually possible to do something like this?

Comment: That's totally impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Its not possible for HTML or JavaScript code to load a windows or mac executable. All you can do is specify

```
<a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com">Send Mail</a>
```

and the browser decides which mail client to open, based on the user preferences

Comment: Yeah, I thought so as well. Just wanted to check with more experienced developers. Thank you for your answer!